# Getting data directly from a website to a hdfs

Tags: hadoop, server, hdfs, flume

How do I get data directly which is entering on a website concurrently on hdfs?

Comment: **What type** of data? You've tagged Flume... All your previous questions include Flume... What's wrong with it? What have you attempted? Please [edit] your question to include more details... http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to have High availability read and writes, then you can use Hbase to store the data.

If you are using REST API, you can store the data directly to Hbase as it has dedicated Hbase REST API that can store into Hbase Tables.

1) Linear and modular scalability.
2) Strictly consistent reads and writes.
3) Automatic and configurable sharding of tables.

For more about HBase :- https://hbase.apache.org/

Else if you want some streaming data into HDFS from any source, you can look into confluent platform ( which has inbuilt kafka ) and can store into HDFS.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Not how to get data from Hadoop onto a website. But from a website into HDFS. Confluent doesn't provide a Javascript driver for website actions, nor should Kafka be exposed to the public internet

Comment: I guess  I mentioned Hbase to save data from website to HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

This entirely depends on *what data you have* and how willing you are to maintain extra tools on top of Hadoop.

if you're just accepting  events from a logfile, Flume, Fluentd, or Filebeat are your best options.

If you are accepting client side events, such as clicks or mouse movements, for example, then you need some backend server accepting those requests. For example, Flume TCP Source, but you probably want some type of authentication endpoint in front of this service to prevent random external messages to your event channel.

You can also use Kafka. The Kafka REST Proxy (by Confluent) can be used to accept REST requests and produce to a Kafka topic. Kafka HDFS Connect (also by Confluent) can consume from Kafka and publish messages to HDFS in near real time, much like Flume

Other options include Apache Nifi or Streamsets. Again, using a TCP or HTTP event source listener with an HDFS destination processor