# Import live data from server to hdfs instantly?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is this possible to load live feed from server to HDFS because I have to load the live feed data on HDFS which is coming via server instantly without any loss of time?

Comment: You should be Hbase or Cassandra for this, not HDFS alone... If you want stream processing, use Kafka

Comment: Also, how is this any different from your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49726697/getting-data-directly-from-a-website-to-a-hdfs

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of technologies that consume data in real time (or near real-time) and have write connectors to hdfs.

- Flume
- Nifi
- Streamsets

are ones I have used.

Comment: Which one has low latency ?

Comment: And through which method in nifi  do I get a data from a remote server and send it into hdfs.